# How do I encrypt every write function call in the system and decrypt every read function call?

Tags: encryption, operating-system, driver, hook, system-calls

I want to make an app similar to Bitlocker. I have to encrypt everything that any application writes to the disk and decrypt everything read from the disk on Windows. I have heard there is a way of hooking system calls, but I need to hook every read/write on the entire operating system. I have also heard I have to write some kind of driver for it, but I really don`t know where to get started. Is there any library that does something like this? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Did you look at how any existing open-source whole-drive encryption programs work, such as dm-crypt or VeraCrypt?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that I need to do on the fly encryption and I think veracrypt only encrypts the drive after unmounting.

Comment: You are wrong about that. VeraCrypt does do on-the-fly encryption.

Comment: Ok, I will check it out then, thank you!